# While, when or as to describe for regular actions

Tags: word-request, time-words

I am trying to find a proper word to use in the following sentence.

> While I am creating a schematic I always try to check every single
>   part several times

Or

> When I am studying I always try to focus on the subject and don't pay
>   attention to anything else

I hope the idea is clear. I want to describe something that I do regularly and put emphasis on an action (positive one).

Please suggest the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While and When:

There is no need for two I personal pronouns in the two clauses:

**While creating a schematic**, I always etc.
**When studying**, I always focus, etc.

As does not apply here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, appreciate your help. But could you please suggest what is better to use in such sentences ? And whether there is any difference between two words ?

Comment: While is during, when is at the time you do something. I am sure those exist in  your mother tongue.

Comment: I disagree with ***as** does not apply here*. Although it would normally come *after* the main clause *(He [does something] **as** he eats)*, there are thousands of written instances of [*As he eats he (does something else too)*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+he+eats+he%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers For  pete's sake: "I want to describe something that I do regularly and put put emphasis on an action (positive one)." /As he eats he does something else too/ does not meet her criteria. Of course one can make as sentence beginning with as. Surely, I was talking stylistics for this purpose and not grammar!

Comment: Simmer down! :) So far as I'm concerned, since it's perfectly possible *grammatically* to use ***as*** instead of ***while/when*** in OP's context (relating to a regular or repeated action), it's misleading of you to assert that it "does not apply here". You're making a stylistic choice (which I would obviously agree with), but the implication of the wording in your answer is that this is a matter of correct/incorrect grammar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are talking down to me by saying there are thousands of written instances of As he eats he. You know I am a native speaker. You have read enough of my posts. It's insulting.

Comment: Thanks for discussion, but in my context is it fine to use `while` ?

Comment: Haven't I answered that??

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123279/while-when-or-as-to-describe-for-regular-actions/123282?noredirect=1#comment248466_123282), in constructions like OP's ***while*** always means ***during*** [some extended period of time]. Although ***when*** is often used with exactly the same sense, it can also be used to mean *at the same **instant** in time*. Consider...

> 1: *While I was watching TV, lightning struck the aerial.*
>    2: *When I was watching TV, lightning struck the aerial.*

...where both ***while*** and ***when*** clearly both mean ***during*** (they both refer to the *period* of time that I was watching TV). But reversing the sequence to...

> 3: ?? *While lightning struck the aerial, I was watching TV.*
>   4: *When lightning struck the aerial, I was watching TV.*

...creates a real problem with #3. Since a lightning strike is [instantaneous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/instantaneous), you must assume I'm referring to an extended period of time during which the aerial was struck more than once - but how could I *continue* to watch TV after the *first* strike?

In practice the default assumption on hearing #3 would be that the speaker doesn't have very good command of English, but in other contexts the ***when/while*** distinction can be used perfectly naturally to convey different meanings.

> 5: *When I hit him, the crowd cheered.*
>    6: *While I hit him, the crowd cheered.*

The default assumption there would be that in #5 I only hit him once, whereas #6 refers to an extended beating. Note that it's at least *possible* for #5 to mean ***each time*** I hit him, but in practice I'd probably use ***whenever*** if that was what I meant.

---

Note that ***as*** is also used to mean ***while, during*** in some contexts, but because it can also mean ***since, because***, it wouldn't usually be used in contexts like OP's example.

It's worth making a couple more points. Firstly, none of the commas in my examples are actually *required*. Secondly, it's perfectly possible to place ***while/when*** between the two clauses (replacing the comma). Doing this makes #3 and #4 semantically equivalent to #1 and #2 (*When he arrived, I left* means the same as *I left when he arrived*; we've just reversed the order of the clauses).